# Unreachable code + how to go through all combinations

Tags: java, math

I want to search through all values from -100 to 100 for a,b and c to find when a√2 - b = c√3 . I know that it's true when a,b and c are 0, but I just wanted to make a program for it.

I don't know what to do in order to get my program to search through every possible combination of a,b and c from -100 to 100. The program that I just created made a,b and c increase by 1 on each iteration, so I couldn't get all of the combinations. I tried to increase the amount of combinations by using "continue;", but it created an "unreachable code" error. This still wouldn't give me all possible combinations.

I also tried to increase a,b and c by 0.001 after every iteration of the loop, by making them doubles. This should have stopped at 0.000..... but instead it continued forever. I found out that this was because some random small number like 9.4524 x 10^-8 (different on every iteration) was added to the end of a,b and c.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = -100;
    int b = -100;
    int c = -100;

    while ((a*Math.sqrt(2)) - b != (c*Math.sqrt(3))) {
        if (a == 100){
            return;
        } else{
            a++;
            System.out.println("a = " + a);
            continue;
        }

        if (b == 100){
            return;
        } else{
            b++;
            System.out.println("b = " + b);
            continue;
        }

        if (c == 100){
            return;
        } else {
            c++;
            System.out.println("c = " + c);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

What could I do to solve the problems above? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: a, b and c are supposed to be integers or doubles?

Comment: You could rearrange b = a√2 - c√3 and test the fractional part of b, thus using only a double loop.

Comment: What with root 2 and root 3 being irrational, I struggle to believe that there are any other whole-numbered solutions other than (0, 0, 0).

Comment: @Andy Turner . Yeah It was from a Cambridge Computer Science admissions test. It took me quite a while to get to it after realising there is no other whole numbered solution/s. I just thought about creating a program for finding the solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the way you're incrementing through the combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c`.  You want to check for each `a`, for each `b`, for each `c` whether a√2 - b = c√3.  Also, to speed up your code, you can cache the values of √2 and √3, since they are constants being recalculated in each iteration.  Also, like you mentioned in your question, you can run into rounding errors in floating point arithmetic.  Therefore, it would be wise to use the static `compare` method of the `Double` class.  You can read about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)).

This code below will print out all the integer combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c` that satisfy the equation a√2 - b = c√3.  If you're just looking for one solution, maybe take the nested for loops and put them in their own method, then when the if condition is met, return that one solution.  You could also make it return a list of solutions by adding each solution that meets the if condition to an `ArrayList`, then returning after the loops complete.

```
public class SurdsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double SQRT2 = Math.sqrt(2);
        final double SQRT3 = Math.sqrt(3);

        for(int a = -100; a <= 100; a++) {
            for(int b = -100; b <= 100; b++) {
                for(int c = -100; c <= 100; c++) {
                    if(Double.compare(a * SQRT2 - b, c * SQRT3) == 0) {
                        System.out.println("a = " + a + "; b = " + b + "; c = " + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I get my code to print out every combination of a, b and c to the console as it is running through them. Also, wouldn't this add 1 to a, b and c at the same time, like mine did (without the "continue;"s). Is that not how for loops work? Sorry, I'm fairly new to Java and haven't written many programs.

Comment: No you're fine. The for loops would start with a=-100, b=-100, and c=-100. Then c will go up by one until it reaches 100. Then c gets reset to -100, and b goes up by one. This repeats again and again until b reaches 100 (and c reaches 100 ninety-nine more times), then b resets to -100 and a increases by 1. That happens over and over until a=100, then after that, the loop finishes.

Comment: Since the for loops are nested, it executes the inner for loop as many times as the outer for loop runs.  So if you had a structure like for(x,1,2){for(y,1,2){for(z,1,2){}}}, it would go through (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), (2,2,2).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Main {
  // a√2 - b = c√3
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    for (int a = -100; a < 100; a++) {
      for (int b = -100; b < 100; b++) {
        for (int c = -100; c < 100; c++) {
          // System.out.println(a +" "+b+" "+c);

          if (BigDecimal.valueOf(a).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(2))).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(b))
              .equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(c).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(3))))) {
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);

          }

        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try.

```
    double sqrt2 = Math.sqrt(2.0);
    double sqrt3 = Math.sqrt(3.0);
    double threshold = 1e-10;
    double from = -100;
    double to = 100;
    double inc = 1.0;

    for (double a = from; a <= to; a += inc) {
        for (double b = from; b <= to; b += inc) {
            for (double c = from; c <= to; c += inc) {

                if ( Math.abs(a * sqrt2 - b - c * sqrt3) < threshold) {
                    System.out.println("a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A few points:

- When you say all numbers between -100 and 100, that's ambiguous.
  There is an unlimited number of real numbers between the two. If
  integers is what you want, that's a finite set. If real numbers are
  your target then you have to pick a good `inc` in the code. The
  smaller the `inc`, the more numbers you are going to try.
- The second part is if your equality should be an approximation. Again, if you want exactly equal, then your only answers are three 0s in which case use `(a * sqrt2 - b == c * sqrt3)` in your `if` condition. But if a few decimal points difference is acceptable, then just pick the right threshold in the above code and you'll have many many more answers.

Answer (score 1):

At first you program does not checking all combinitions. It starts with a=-100
b=-100 c=-100 but in each iteration a b and c increases by 1. It means that in each iteration a==b and b==c.
To check all possible combinitions use this loop

```
public class BruteChecker{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(double a = -100;a <= 100;a++){
            for(double b = -100; b <= 100; b++){
                for(double c =-100; c <= 100; c++){
                    if(a * Math.sqrt(2) - b == c * Math.sqrt(3)){
                        System.out.println(a + " * sqrt(2) - " + b + " = " + c + " * sqrt(3)");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```